# justify-content making a gap on the left side

Tags: html, css, flexbox

At the bottom, button Git and link "10 min read" and the image are in the same  (first two are in the one, the third is for itself).

When i try to justify-content, the gap creates on the left side of button and link. I don't know how all this looks when put on this site, because it's my first time using it, so I'm really sorry.

It's my third day using Html and CSS so have mercy.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Practice #1</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <img
        class="logo"
        src="https://shapingthefuture.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/envato-logo-small.svg"
        alt="logo"
      />
      <div class="header-right">
        <button href="#" class="sign-in">Sign in</button>
        <button href="#" class="get-started">Get started</button>
      </div>
    </header>
    <nav>
      <h1>Quick Code</h1>
      <a href="#" class="nav-link"> Top courses</a>
      <a href="#" class="nav-link">✍ Submit article</a>
      <a href="#" class="nav-link"> Web dev</a>
      <a href="#" class="nav-link"> Mobile dev</a>
      <a href="#" class="nav-link"> Programming</a>
      <a href="#" class="nav-link quick">Quick code</a>
    </nav>

    <article>
      <p class="free-story">
        You have <strong>1</strong> free member-only story left this month.
        <a href="#" class="for-medium"
          >Sign up for Medium and get an extra one</a
        >
      </p>
      <div class="in-article">
        <h2>10 Reasons Why You Should Switch to Linux</h2>
        <p class="ten-things">10 Things Linux Can Do That Windows Can't</p>
        <div class="samul-social">
          <div class="samuel">
            <img class="samuel-img"
            src="https://www.kindpng.com/picc/m/171-1712282_profile-icon-png-profile-icon-vector-png-transparent.png"/
            alt="samuel-martins">
            <div class="to-name">
              <p>Samuel Martins</p>
              <button class="follow">Follow</button>
            </div>
            <p class="date">Nov 17 &middot; 6 min read</p>
          </div>
          <div class="social">
            <a href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank"
              ><img
                class="icon"
                src="https://seeklogo.com/images/T/twitter-icon-circle-blue-logo-0902F48837-seeklogo.com.png"
                alt="twitter-logo"
            /></a>
            <a href="https://rs.linkedin.com/" target="_blank"
              ><img
                class="icon"
                src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/ca/LinkedIn_logo_initials.png/640px-LinkedIn_logo_initials.png"
                alt="linkedin-logo"
            /></a>
            <a href="facebook.com" target="_blank">
              <img class="icon"
              src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/05/Facebook_Logo_%282019%29.png/800px-Facebook_Logo_%282019%29.png"/
              alt="facebook-logo"/>
            </a>
            <a href="index.html">
              <img
                class="icon"
                src="https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/thumbnails/005/200/965/small/bookmark-black-color-icon-vector.jpg"
            /></a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <img
          class="main-image"
          src="https://www.uveta.io/categories/blog/windows-vs-linux-appservice-whats-the-difference/windows_linux.png"
          alt="main-picture"
        />

        <p class="counting">
          This is going to be a pretty straight forward article. I am aware that
          it might get a lot of negative comments from Windows users just from
          reading the title alone. I believe these are the reasons why everyone
          should try using the Linux system.
        </p>
        <p class="dots">&sdot; &sdot; &sdot;</p>
        <h3>1. You can download the source for Linux</h3>
        <p class="counting">
          I believe in transparency when it comes to the digital world. You can
          go over to
          <a
            href="https://github.com/torvalds/linux"
            class="link-in-article"
            target="_blank"
            >https://github.com/torvalds/linux</a
          >
          and download over 800k commits for Linux. You will be able to see
          everything that has ever been done on Linux all the way back from its
          inception. Why would anyone even care about the source code? Well, the
          reason you are going to want to care is that there are people who are
          constantly looking at the source for things like bugs and security
          issues, and various other matters.
        </p>
        <p class="counting">
          You can see the ins and outs of the system you are using. With
          Windows, everything is completely closed, which means you are putting
          a hundred percent of your trust into Microsoft developers to check
          their own stuff and make sure it is okay. Even if you do not care
          about the source, know that there are a lot of people who do care, and
          they make your experience better as a result. In addition to the Linux
          kernel being open source, almost all software that you will install
          for your system comes from official repositories, which are also open
          source.
        </p>

        <h3>2. You can install updates without rebooting your machine</h3>
        <p class="counting">
          This is a game-changer for cloud environments. If you have a windows
          server, you have to upgrade your software then reboot the system
          again. This will result in your users experiencing downtime. With
          Linux, you can update almost anything without a reboot, and for
          kernels version 4.0 and beyond, you can even update the kernel itself.
          Isn’t that amazing? I have never liked the Windows prompt for a reboot
          every time I install or update a piece of software.
        </p>

        <h3>
          3. You can plug devices in without worrying about finding and
          downloading drivers
        </h3>
        <p class="counting">
          The only time it is not true is with highly specialized devices. How
          is that possible? The whole point of the Linux kernel is to connect
          hardware to software. In the Linux kernel, there have been over 16,000
          unique developers across 1400 companies working on Linux writing their
          drivers into Linux. That way, when people use Linux, it is just
          automatically there. When you look at windows, you have to download
          and install drivers every time you hook something into your computer.
        </p>
        <h3>4. You can run Linux from a pen drive, CD DVD, or any medium</h3>
        <p class="counting">
          I cannot stress the importance of this. I mean, imagine having your
          whole system on a thumb-drive. You can take your work literally
          anywhere without the risk of losing it. Of course, it works best if
          you have persistence configured during installation into the drive.
          For developers, this can be useful in situations where you are
          required on-site but cannot carry your laptop. Hackers use this trick
          all the to boot Kali live or with persistence because that is
          basically all they need half the time. Another advantage with this
          trick is that you can install multiple distributions in one
          thumb-drive so that you can boot into whichever one you wish at any
          given time.
        </p>

        <h3>5. You can run the Linux for a long time without rebooting</h3>
        <p class="counting">
          This is possible without degradation of performance because Linux is
          ultra-stable. It has way less memory fragmentation, and it simply does
          not become slower over time. You will still be able to make changes on
          the fly without the need to reboot. You are just simply not going to
          find that kind of up-time on any Windows system. The advantage is that
          you can run a production server for a long time while making any
          changes without system reboot and, therefore, no downtime.
        </p>

        <h3>6. You could run the Linux on almost any hardware</h3>
        <p class="counting">
          When I say any hardware, I am referring to both different types of
          hardware, as well as hardware from various date ranges. There are
          fully functional Linux installs that are, in some cases, less than
          32MB in size. This means that you can go into that closet, dust off
          that old computer from 1993, and breathe new life into it by
          installing an appropriate Linux system with respect to your space. You
          cannot do that with windows. As Windows gets newer, it becomes more
          resource-intensive, and the minimum requirements go up. Linux has a
          wide range of distributions from which you can pick one that you need
          for your particular application. You can
          <a
            href="https://blog.coursesity.com/best-kali-linux-tutorials/"
            class="link-in-article"
            target="_blank"
            >learn Linux</a
          >
          to develop your website at low costs, as it can run almost any of the
          major languages.
        </p>

        <h3>
          7. You can fix broken Linux installs with a live CD DVD or pen drive
        </h3>
        <p class="counting">
          This is not for Linux alone. You can even fix broken windows installs
          with Linux in some cases. The reason this is possible is that the
          Linux kernel runs entirely in memory. So you can use a CD or pen
          driver DVD to load that kernel into memory, and then go into a chroot
          environment on your broken system, and then you can use that broken
          system as if it were functioning. From there, you can take whatever
          action you need to get that system working again. On windows, you have
          to go through the windows system repair wizard. If that does not work,
          you will be required to re-install windows.
        </p>

        <h3>
          8. You can update all of your software often with a single command
        </h3>
        <p class="counting">
          In a Debian system, it is so easy to update your software and even
          upgrade the entire system if you wish. You need only type apt-get
          update or apt-get update && apt-get upgrade. On windows, you either
          use the built-in updater for the software, or you go back to the site
          to download a newer version, which may cost you. As a developer, I
          cannot stress the importance of using updated software.
        </p>

        <h3>9. You can move a hard drive from one Linux machine to another</h3>
        <p class="counting">
          So, the motherboard from my laptop died about a week ago, and I did
          not have enough money to get a new one or an entirely new laptop. I
          had to take my hard drive from the broken laptop and use it on a
          different laptop. Guess what? It worked without re-installation. I
          never lost my data, and I am actually using the other laptop to write
          this article. This is largely made possible by the fact that all the
          drivers in Linux are built-in. Moving a hard drive from one machine to
          another does not affect it. It simply sees all your new hardware and
          re-acclimate to work like it was in the previous machine. On windows,
          not only will it probably not work, but windows will see that you have
          different hardware, and then, suddenly, your copy of Windows becomes
          non-genuine.
        </p>

        <h3>
          10. You can install software without worrying about viruses and
          malware
        </h3>
        <p class="counting">
          Now, this is not to say that Linux is virus and malware proof. It is
          just to say that it is a lot harder for viruses and malware to get on
          your system. That is due to two things. Number one, it is harder to
          escalate privileges on Linux for just a normal user. Number two, most
          of the software that you download for Linux comes from official
          repositories, and those are guaranteed. Additionally, software on
          Linux does not autorun as they do on windows. This also implies that
          there is no antivirus software needed on Linux, and of course, that
          saves you money.
        </p>
        <p class="dots">&sdot; &sdot; &sdot;</p>
        <p class="counting">
          I am not trying to convince you to switch. You will not lose anything
          by trying it out. Every single reason is basically a comparison to
          Windows. I have used windows before and I slowly grew apart from it
          when I discovered Linux. I have never been worried about not having a
          legal copy of Linux nor the need to buy Linux software. Everything
          about Linux is open-source. Don’t worry about not knowing how to use
          Linux at first. There is a huge community to guide you. In case you
          are wondering where Linux is used in the real world, check out another
          article I wrote on the different places Linux is used.
        </p>
        <a
          class="what-is-used-for"
          href="https://samuel-martins.medium.com/what-is-linux-used-for-6714041a9a0b"
          target="_blank"
        >
          <div class="used-for-text">
            <p class="what-is">What Is Linux Used For?</p>
            <p class="linux-is">
              Linux Is Taking Over. It Is Just a Matter of Time
            </p>
            <p class="samuel-martins">samuel.martins.medium.com</p>
          </div>
          <img src="25719.png"/ alt="linux image" class="used-for-image">
        </a>
      </div>
    </article>
    <div class="developer-box">
      <p class="sign-for-developer">Sign up for Developer Updates</p>
      <p class="by-quick-code">By Quick Code</p>
      <p class="receive-updates">
        Receive weekly updates about new posts on programming, development, data
        science, web development and more
        <a href="https://medium.com/quick-code/newsletters/developer-updates" class="receive-updates-link"
          >Take a look.</a
        >
        <br />
        <div class="email">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Your email" class="input-email"/>
        <button class="get-this-newsletter">✉ Get this newsletter</button>
        </div>
        <p class="by-sign-in">By signing up, you will create a Medium account if you don’t already have one. Review our <a href="https://policy.medium.com/medium-privacy-policy-f03bf92035c9?source=newsletter_v3_promo--------------------------newsletter_v3_promo-----------" class="privacy-policy">Privacy Policy</a> for more information about our privacy practices.</p>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="after-box">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="more-from-quick-code">
          <div class="more-and-follow">
            <a href="https://medium.com/quick-code" class="more-from" target="_blank">More from Quick Code
            </a>
            <button class="follow-two">Follow</button>
           </div>
          <p class="find-the-best-tutorials">Find the best tutorials and courses for the web, mobile, chatbot, AR/VR development, <br> database management, data science, web design and cryptocurrency. Practice in<br> JavaScript, Java, Python, R, Android, Swift, Objective-C, React, Node Js, Ember,<br> C++, SQL & more.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="top-10-git-gui-clients">
        </div>
        <div class="theme-all"></div>
          <a href="https://medium.com/quick-code/top-10-git-gui-clients-for-developers-b56d702579a6" class="top-ten-git-gui-clients">
           <div class="theme-up">
            <img src="https://miro.medium.com/fit/c/176/176/1*1wwrri468OAME5L00uD-jA.jpeg" alt="Theme Selection"/ class="theme-logo">
            <p class="theme-selection">Theme Selection</p>
            <p class="mid-dot"> &middot; </p>
            <p class="theme-date">Nov 10, 2020</p>
           </div>
           <div class="theme-middle">
            <div class="theme-text">
              <div class="theme-text-up">
                <p class="theme-h">Top 10+ Git GUI Clients For Developers ‍</p>
               <p class="theme-par">Hey there.!!‍♂️ Are you looking for the top git GUI client to make it easy to manage your project? Then you are in right place..!! First of all, Git is a popular version control system that helps developers, writers, or anyone...</p>
              </div>
              <div class="theme-bot">
                <div class="theme-bot-left">
                  <a href="https://medium.com/tag/git" target="_blank"><button>Git</button></a>
                  <a href="https://medium.com/quick-code/top-10-git-gui-clients-for-developers-b56d702579a6?source=post_page-----e037aa748504----0----------------------------"
                  target="_blank">10 min read</a>
                </div>
                <img src="bookmark-icon-12326.png"class="theme-bot-right" />
             </div>
            </div>
             <img src="https://miro.medium.com/fit/c/101/101/1*Mi1xLQIarZQaBNYReu8Z0g.png"/ class="theme-pic">
           </div>
          </a>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  width: 1400px;
  margin: auto;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 10px 10px;
}

.logo {
  width: 60px;
}

.sign-in {
  font-size: 22px;
  padding: 14px 19px;
  border: 0;
  background-color: white;
  color: #7a6efe;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.sign-in:hover {
  background-color: #7a6efe;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.get-started {
  font-size: 22px;
  padding: 12px 17px;
  border: 2px #7a6efe solid;
  background-color: white;
  color: #7a6efe;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.get-started:hover {
  background-color: #7a6efe;
  color: white;
}

nav {
  background-color: #7a6efe;
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.nav-link {
  display: grid;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  height: 50px;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav-link:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: #7a6efe;
}

.quick {
  grid-column: 7 / 8;
}

article {
  width: 800px;
  margin: auto;
}

.free-story {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  align-self: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 70px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.for-medium {
  color: black;
}

.for.medium:visited {
  color: black;
}

.in-article {
  width: 776px;
  margin: auto;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 55px;
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.ten-things {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #999999;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.samuel {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50px 1fr;
  column-gap: 10px;
  row-gap: 0px;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.samuel-img {
  width: 50px;
  height: auto;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}

.to-name {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 5px;
}

.date {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
}

.follow {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: #7a6efe 1px solid;
  padding: 3px 8px;
  color: #7a6efe;
}

.follow:hover {
  background-color: #7a6efe;
  color: white;
}

.samul-social {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.social {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
}

.icon {
  width: 30px;
}

.main-image {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.counting {
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

h3 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-weight: 800;
}

.link-in-article {
  color: black;
}

.link-in-article:visited {
  color: black;
}

.dots {
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.what-is-used-for {
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px rgb(204, 204, 204) solid;
  text-decoration: none;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  margin-top: 60px;
}

.used-for-text {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.used-for-image {
  border-left: 1px rgb(204, 204, 204) solid;
  height: 199px;
}

.what-is {
  color: black;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
}

.linux-is {
  color: #999999;
  font-size: 22px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.samuel-martins {
  color: #999999;
}

.developer-box {
  width: 776px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-top: #7a6efe 5px solid;
  padding: 45px;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.sign-for-developer {
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.by-quick-code {
  font-size: 13px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.receive-updates {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

.receive-updates-link {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
}

.receive-updates-link:after {
  content: "";

  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 1px;

  border-width: 0 0 1px;
  border-style: solid;
}

.email {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: sohne, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.input-email {
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(168, 168, 168);
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 350px;
  font-size: 17px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  color: rgb(168, 168, 168);
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.input-email:focus {
  outline: none;
  color: rgb(80, 80, 80);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(80, 80, 80);
}

.get-this-newsletter {
  background-color: #7a6efe;
  color: white;
  border: 0;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.get-this-newsletter:hover {
  background-color: #6f61ff;
}

.by-sign-in {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

.privacy-policy {
  color: black;
}

.privacy-policy:visited {
  color: black;
}

.after-box {
  width: 1200px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.content {
  width: 776px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.more-from-quick-code {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.more-and-follow {
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 45px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.more-from {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.more-from:visited {
  color: black;
}

.follow-two {
  background-color: #7a6efe;
  color: white;
  border: 0;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 17px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.follow-two:hover {
  background-color: #6f61ff;
}

.find-the-best-tutorials {
  line-height: 1.4;
  color: #7e7e7e;
}

.top-ten-git-gui-clients {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.theme-up {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.theme-logo {
  width: 25px;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.theme-selection {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.mid-dot {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.theme-date {
  margin-left: 10px;
  color: #7e7e7e;
}

.theme-middle {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.theme-h {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 750;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.theme-par {
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.theme-pic {
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
}

.theme-text {
  display: grid;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.theme-bot {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.theme-bot-left {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the code, you can see a hidden anchor tag inside the "themebot" div.
You could simply set the display to none or the position to absolute. But you should find out, why the anchor tag is appearing, if it is unintended.

```
.top-ten-git-gui-clients {
    display: none;
}
```